# Alternate for Request.RawUrl in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, request, rawurl

I was using a `Request.RawUrl` to get the URL after localhost. i.e if my url is `localhost:52482/something/somethingelse`, then this used to return `/something/somethingelse`.

I accessed this in a base controller(MVC3).But i found out that if there are some entries made in the page ,say some textbox and other selections, this would return a query string kind of value. How do I solve this?

I was thinking about perform this operation in javascript to see if i can get just the URL without query string. Let me know how should I proceed here?

Thanks,
Adarsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

```
// testsite.com/test.html?q=blah

var urlWithoutQS = window.location.host + window.location.pathname

alert(urlWithoutQS);                // testsite.com/test.html
alert(urlWithoutQS.split('/')[0]);  // testsite.com
alert(urlWithoutQS.split('/')[1]);  // test.html
```

Comment: Thanks, any alternative in server side?